# Implement SSO with google account

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, single-sign-on, google-oauth

Im trying to implement sso with google and 3rd party application.
The idea is the user will log in to google, once he will request the 3rd party application page the SSO handler should take place.

From the SSO handler I should be able to retrieve the logged in google user, just email address.
What is the best approach to implement such a solution, i was thinking with python + oauth.
I should be able to get user email with the requests headers.
SO the flow is:
1. User authenticate vs google
2. User invoke SSO handler by trying to access 3rd party application
3. SSO Handler get current google logged in user -> how do i preform this API call?
4. Once the user email is retrieved, the SSO handler will authenticate against the 3rd party application.

I wasn't able to find information regarding it, any guidelines will he helpful. Thanks!

Edit:
I tried to play with authomatic but didnt made much progress

Here is some sample code:

```
CONFIG = {

    'google': {
        'class_': 'authomatic.providers.oauth2.Google',
        'id': authomatic.provider_id(),  # returns 2
        'consumer_key': 'XXXXXX',
        'consumer_secret': 'XXXXXX',
        'scope': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
                  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']
    }
}

class Login(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def any(self, provider_name):
        result = authomatic.login(Webapp2Adapter(self), 'google')
        if result:
            if result.user:
                result.user.update()
                self.response.write('<h1>Hi {0}</h1>'.format(result.user.name))

authomatic = Authomatic(config=CONFIG, secret='sadfasdfsgfr')
Login(webapp2.get_request())
```

Im getting the following error:

AssertionError: Request global variable is not set.

Comment: Have look at authomatic it may provide what you want. http://peterhudec.github.io/authomatic/

Comment: @TimHoffman thanks for the reply. i tried playing around with authomatic, i find their docuemation quite lacking since most of the examples require configuration that is not mentioned. i added authomatic configuration to my original questions